# Conditionally select element positions of objects in list and return new list with object element positions

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of many objects; in the case of this MWE - only 6. I am interested in selecting the position of an element for objects `msfr`, `msfl`, `mshr` and `mshl` which correspond to the respective value in `vms` (this object holds the maximum value of the elements in the 'ms...' objects) and where `scheduled.day` corresponds with `day. My objective is to return a second list of objects (the 'ms...' objects) holding the position of the elements where the conditions are true. Here is the data:

```
l <- list(msfr=c(1,5,0,0,0),
          msfl=c(1,4,0,5,0),
          mshr=c(1,0,0,0,0),
          mshl=c(0,0,0,0,4),
          vms= c(1,5,0,5,4),
          scheduled.day = c(0, 3, 0, 4, 3)) 
today <- 3
ctt<- which(l[["scheduled.day"]] == today)
```

The closest I have come to achieving my objective is with the following code. But by using `%in%` element positions are being returned for the object `msfl`.

```
obj.names <-  names(l)[1:4]
l2 <- lapply(lapply(l[obj.names],"["), function(x){which(x %in% l[["vms"]][ctt])}) # ctt being ignored

> l2
$msfr
[1] 2

$msfl
[1] 2 4

$mshr
integer(0)

$mshl
[1] 5
```

What I am looking for is some neat code that will return a list that looks like this.

```
l3 <- list(msfr = 2,
           mshl = 5)

> l3
$msfr
[1] 2

$mshl
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I must be blind!

```
lapply(lapply(l[obj.names],"["), function(x){which(x == l[["vms"]] & l[["scheduled.day"]] == today)})
```

I don't know why I didn't try this before,  but it does the trick. If anyone has an alternative solution, I would be glad to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to convert it to `data.frame`, then do a `group` by subset to return a `summarised` index and finally convert to `list`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
enframe(l[obj.names]) %>%
     unnest(c(value)) %>%
     group_by(name) %>% 
     summarise(rn = list(row_number()[value ==l[['vms']] & l[["scheduled.day"]] == today])) %>%
     unnest(c(rn)) %>%
     deframe %>% 
     as.list
#$msfr
#[1] 2

#$mshl
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the second time in two days where you have answered my question. Cheers mate!